# URL formation in Chrome or Firefox or IE

Tags: browser

I have seen this in one of the tutorial videos.
The tutor used firefox and typed in url box like google 'stackoverflow' and it formed the url as https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow. (This is just an example).

I think it will be a very useful feature. 
Like, i have a ticketing system whose url is always like this - http://ticket-system.com/Tickets.aspx?Ticket=1000 where 1000 is the ticket number.

I want to be able to go to url box in browser and type 'Ticket 1000', and it should form the url by itself and redirect to there.

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here 
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95653?hl=en&ref_topic=14676

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95655

> Start typing the web address of the site you want to search in the
>   address bar. If Google Chrome has a record of the site's search
>   engine, it automatically offers you the option to search that site. If
>   you remember the search engine's keyword, you can also type the
>   keyword in the address bar. Press Tab to choose the search engine,
>   type your search term, then press Enter.